# Get items in order selected from listbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I would like to deselect the last selected index if the user already selected more than 3 items (Only allow user to remove selections).

`sender.selectedIndex` returns the first selected listbox item and not the last (chronologically) one. Does anyone have any tips how I could achieve this?

example (* selected)

```
item1
*item2
item3
*item4
item5
```

if I select item3 then `sender.selectedIndex` contains item2 (first item) and `sender.selectedItems` contains item2,item3,item4 so I can't tell which one is new.

Comment: listBOX (from question text) or listVIEW (title) very big difference

Comment: sorry, I have one that does store them in order and forgot it was something I added.  You'll have to create your own collection and update it as they select items.

Comment: You could always use the method where you have 2 listboxes and a ">>" button to move an items from lbA to lbB.  lbB would always have them in selected order and the user could see what they are working with...like Playlist in WMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track and compare your own list against `SelectedIndexes` updating as needed. Apparently, the LB just iterates the items collection in order to build the `Selecteditems` collection, so it would always be in the same order as the items.

Is it overkill?  Only if the app doesnt really need this level of detail.  Otherwise, if you need it, you need it.

```
Private cList As New List(Of Integer)       ' our new Selected Indicies

Private Sub lb_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, 
        e As EventArgs) Handles lb.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim ndxCol As ListBox.SelectedIndexCollection
    ndxCol = lb.SelectedIndices

    ' add missing ones
    For Each n As Integer In ndxCol
        If cList.Contains(n) = False Then
            cList.Add(n)
        End If
    Next

    ' remove old ones
    For n As Integer = cList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ndxCol.Contains(cList(n)) = False Then
            cList.Remove(cList(n))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```